# Symfony/serializer Normalize Object in Object

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

Hi all need little help I didn't find a response about recursive normalize object

```php
    class User
    {
        public $email;
        public $userId;
        public $userName;
        /**
         * @var CustomAttributes
         */
        public $customAttributes;
    }
    class CustomAttributes
    {
        public $someStuff;
        public $someStuffHere;
    }
```

I just want to transform this into an array snake_case via normalize() of symfony component

```php
$normalizer = new PropertyNormalizer(null, new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter());
$user_normalize = $normalizer->normalize($user);
```

but I have this error

> In AbstractObjectNormalizer.php line 129:
>                                                                                       Cannot normalize attribute "customAttributes" because the injected
>   serializer is not a normalizer

Thx for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you forgot to add `$serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer])` bit. See the working example below.

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
use App\User;
use App\CustomAttributes;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\PropertyNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

class SnakeCaseUtility
{
    public function convert(): array
    {
        $classMetadataFactory = null;
        $nameConverter = new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter();

        $normalizer = new PropertyNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, $nameConverter);
        $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer]);

        $normalizedUser = $serializer->normalize($this->getUser(), 'json');

        return $normalizedUser;
    }

    private function getUser(): User
    {
        $customAttributes = new CustomAttributes();
        $customAttributes->someStuff = 'Some stuff';
        $customAttributes->someStuffHere = 'Some stuff here';

        $user = new User();
        $user->userId = 123;
        $user->userName = 'Hello World';
        $user->email = 'hello@world.com';
        $user->customAttributes = $customAttributes;

        return $user;
    }
}
```

**TEST**

```
use App\SnakeCaseUtility;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SnakeCaseUtilityTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSnakeCase(): void
    {
        $expected = [
            'email' => 'hello@world.com',
            'user_id' => 123,
            'user_name' => 'Hello World',
            'custom_attributes' => [
                'some_stuff' => 'Some stuff',
                'some_stuff_here' => 'Some stuff here',
            ]
        ];

        $this->assertSame($expected, (new SnakeCaseUtility())->convert());
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit --filter SnakeCaseUtilityTest tests/SnakeCaseUtilityTest.php 
PHPUnit 7.5.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 83 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: Thank you so much very helpfull.
Very strange to create a serializer to normalize and not just a Normalizer but it's ok that's work :)